# color property changing of a button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

How can I change the color of a button when it is clicked in asp.net? In my code color is changing when mouse over it. But I need to change when button clicking.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps i'm missing something obvious, but isn't it as simple as:

Change `onmouseover` to `onclick`.

If you want to do it on serverside, handle it's `Click` event and:

```
 Button1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
 Button1.BackColor = Color.Black;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<asp:Button Text="Save" ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_Click" runat="server" />
```

code behind

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnSave.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
```

Comment: If his answer was best for you, then you should click the checkbox under the vote up/down to accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
OnClientClick="this.src='Images/image.jpg';return false;"
```

add that to your button line's source

Comment: thnx for ur answer,Prospector

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<input id="btnTest" type="button" value="Test"/>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnTest").click(function() {
              $("#btnTest").css("background-color","red");
        });
    });
```

Comment: thnx for ur answer,Jeet Bhatt